# Trying to display an array, but only its even numbers

Tags: javascript

```
const sampleArray = [
  469,
  " " + 755,
  " " + 244,
  " " + 245,
  " " + 758,
  " " + 450,
  " " + 302,
  " " + 20,
  " " + 712,
  " " + 71,
  " " + 456,
  " " + 21,
  " " + 398,
  " " + 339,
  " " + 882,
  " " + 848,
  " " + 179,
  " " + 535,
  " " + 940,
  " " + 472,
];



let mainDiv10 = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph10 = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode10 = document.createTextNode("KATA 11");
myParagraph10.append(myTextNode10);
mainDiv10.append(myParagraph10);
let max9 = 100;
let oneToTwentyFive10 = [];
function array2() {
  if (sampleArray % 2 === 0) mainDiv10.append(sampleArray + "  ");
}
array2();
```

My HTML is all corret but I know something is wrong with my javascript syntax. I got the array to `console.log` and also appear on my HTML page but not the even numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, [edit your question title and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557084/trying-to-display-an-array-but-only-its-even-numbers#) in order to remove uppercase (it makes people less productive)

Comment: where is your loop, how does it work?

Comment: im just so confused as how to take the array but output only the evens i know i use the modulo symbol and anything modulo 2 " % 2" and === 0 is even but how would i even say that about a array in java??

Comment: im a tottal noob how would i do a for loop with a array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, if you add a space in number (`" " + 755,`) then you cannot check if is a even number. Not only but you have to iterate in `sampleArray` to verify if an element is even.

You could use a `forEach` function. Like this example:

```js
const sampleArray = [
  469,
  755,
  244,
  245,
  758,
  450,
  302,
  20,
  712,
  71,
  456,
  21,
  398,
  339,
  882,
  848,
  179,
  535,
  940,
  472,
];



let mainDiv10 = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph10 = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode10 = document.createTextNode("KATA 11");
myParagraph10.append(myTextNode10);
mainDiv10.append(myParagraph10);
let max9 = 100;
let oneToTwentyFive10 = [];
function array2() {
  sampleArray.forEach(el => {
     if (el % 2 === 0) mainDiv10.append(el + "  ");
  })
  
}
array2();
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: that tottally worked! your a genius could you explain how that worked? like what does foreach do?

Comment: Thank you :) `forEach` function is quite simple. If you have an array and you want to iterate in each value, then you call `myarray.forEach(element => { /* here you can manage every element of the array*/  })`. `forEach` function has another useful declaration: `myarray.forEach((element, index) => { /*here you have element and index of the element in array*/ })`. For more info you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) page

Comment: one last question if i could

 function array2() {
  sampleArray.forEach(el => {
     if (el % 2 === 0) mainDiv10.append(el + "  ");
  })
it says equal or greater than but theres nothing there except the if statment and the conditional? what would it be => to?

Comment: This symbol `=>` is the symbol of the `arrow function` (you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arrow_functions)). In this case, arrow function is just a more compact version of `function(el) { ... }`. You know, javascript programmers love to make the code compact :)